# Import of a Visual Studio Solution not generating the diagram in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm importing the Visual Studio Solution file from  Develop > Source Code > Solutions > Import a Visual Studio Solution.

There is no error displayed and no diagram created.

When I import from  Develop > Source Code > Files > Import Source Directory, the diagram is created.

How can I import a Solution file to EA? I've included the screenshot which includes the differences of these two import methods.

Sparx Enterprise Architect: version 16.1.1628 - 64 bit - Unified Edition
Visual Studio Solution: TargetFramework .net 6.0

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but EA only RE source code (directories) and no VS solution. Geert will have the right answer (later then).

Comment: @qwerty_so, I've updated the screenshot that includes the options to import the visual studio solution. Hope that would help.

Comment: I see. It's not my area, but looks like (another) EA bug. Wait for Geert to answer. He knows for sure.

Comment: What do you get exactly when you import a solution? I just tried myself, and for my C# solution it worked just fine. I got all classes and interfaces, and even a class diagram per package.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens, as included in right side of the attached image, 
the Package1 > WebApiTestForEA is imported by  "Develop > Source Code > Solutions > Import a Visual Studio Solution" method. It does not display any diagram.
the Package2 > WebApiTestForEA is imported by "Develop > Source Code > Files > Import Source Directory" method. It generate class diagrams.

Comment: You might have a situation that is not supported by EA. I would try to send in a bug report to get an answer from Sparx.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like EA doesn't support "new" (few years old) csproj format. Loading source works fine, solution can't be loaded but projects itself are discovered correctly.